# Form in Rails not saving input data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, parameters

I have a form in a Rails app that is not saving the input data. It seems there is something I'm missing but I don't know what.

The controller looks like this:

```
   def new
      @blog_post = BlogPost.new
   end

   def create
      @blog_post = BlogPost.new(blog_post_params)
       if @blog_post.save
       redirect_to @blog_post_path
     end
   end

   def blog_post_params
     params.require(:blog_post).permit(:title, :blurb, :content, :image)
   end
 end
```

And the form like this:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
    <%= form_for (@blog_post) do |b| %>
    <%= b.text_field :title, placeholder: :title, class: "form-control" %><br>
    <%= b.text_field :blurb, placeholder: :blurb, class: "form-control" %><br>
    <%= b.text_area :content, placeholder: :content, class: "form-control" %> 
<div class="field">
    <%= b.file_field :image %></div><br>
    <%= b.submit ("Submit"), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
</form>
```

I haven't added the uploader yet but I don't think this should make any difference. I have also added data to the model from the console and this appears in my index page. So it seems to be the case that the data is just not saving in the form - but I have no idea why this would be. Much appreciation to anyone who can assist :-)

EDIT

The server log looks like this:

```
Started GET "/blog_posts/new? 
utf8=%E2%9C%93&authenticity_token=2IuVGQaet%2Bsi2GU57Ukrvit83HVyYely1Tw 
RqDnYZvFAWpGQm7uVCrOvM70BJd82UNy3a5XfUtGl9Lz21Lzb5A%3D%3D&blog_post%5Btitle% 
5D=asd&blog_post%5Bblurb%5D=asdf&blog_post%5Bcontent%5D=asdfg&blog_post%5Bimag 
e%5D=&commit=Submit" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-10 10:37:18 +0800
Processing by BlogPostsController#new as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", 
"authenticity_token"=>"2IuVGQaet+si2GU57Ukrvit83HVyYely1TwRqDnYZvFAWpGQm7uVCr 
OvM70BJd82UNy3a5XfUtGl9Lz21Lzb5A==", "blog_post"=>{"title"=>"asd", 
"blurb"=>"asdf", "content"=>"asdfg", "image"=>""}, "commit"=>"Submit"}
Rendering blog_posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application
Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (1.1ms)
Rendered blog_posts/new.html.erb within layouts/application (6.1ms)
Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.5ms)
Completed 200 OK in 34ms (Views: 31.8ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

and the index:

```
Started GET "/blog_posts" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-04-10 10:52:07 +0800
Processing by BlogPostsController#index as HTML
  Rendering blog_posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered shared/_navbar.html.erb (0.7ms)
  BlogPost Load (0.2ms)  SELECT "blog_posts".* FROM "blog_posts"
  Rendered blog_posts/index.html.erb within layouts/application (3.5ms)
  Rendered shared/_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 27ms (Views: 24.5ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

Comment: can you please provide your server log?

Comment: That's done. I couldn't see anything there either

Comment: it's for new action. can you provide logs when blog_post create an action called?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not exactly sure what you mean, but the only other action right now is GET index, so I added the server log of this.

Comment: @Robert, what do you have in logs right after click on the 'Submit' button?

Comment: @vasilisa I think this was included in the above log. After the authenticity token, the fields have been completed and then submit.

Comment: @Robert, by some reason you form goes to `/blog_posts` with GET, not POST verb. Maybe it is because improper work of `form_for` inside the `form` tag. Try to remove outer form tag (you don't need it, form_for generates it for you) and add the generated form html from your page

Comment: @Vasilisa when you say 'outer form tag' do you mean the HTML form class?

Comment: @Robert, yes, I mean - <form class="form-horizontal"> and </form>

Comment: @Vasilisa that seems to be it - thank you so much :-)

Comment: @Robert, you are welcome :)

Answer (score -1):

Your form is not correct. Here the modified form

```
    <%= form_for (@blog_post, :html => { class: "form-control" }) do |b| %>
     <%= b.text_field :title, placeholder: :title, class: "form-control" %><br>
     <%= b.text_field :blurb, placeholder: :blurb, class: "form-control" %><br>
     <%= b.text_area :content, placeholder: :content, class: "form-control" %> 
     <div class="field">
     <%= b.file_field :image %></div><br>
      <%= b.submit ("Submit"), class: "btn btn-primary" %>
    <% end %>
```

Hope it should work.

Comment: No, that just threw up a syntax error. This code is unfamiliar to me so I can't really be too sure about it.